# how do i accurately calculate my layout (button) height relative to screen size?

Tags: java, android, layout

Hey everyone im currently working on my first app and im facing a strange problem.
I have 5 buttons in my layout of which the height is calculated by a function to get the right size for every screen.

The function works fine and almost correctly sets the height for each button except for a tiny little line at the bottom, I guess it's some kind of rounding error?

Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction, i cant figure this out.
Thanks in advance.

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int minusthis = 0;

    Context context = this;
    int resource = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resource > 0) {
        minusthis = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resource);
    }

    int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels - minusthis;

    int tilesize = (screenHeight / 5);
```

As you can see I get the displayMetrics and divide them by 5 because i have 5 tiles which have to be exactly 1/5 of the screen.
"tilesize" will be applied to the buttons in the code later on.

[app running on Nexus6p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJFNU.png)

In the picture I attatched you can see the buttons get stretched almost correctly over the screen except for the tiny white line I circled in red.
The line may seem small but I cant make it disappear and it really annoys me, also it becomes more apparent in other activities where I have differently sized buttons and panels.

So if you've read this far, thank you already! If you see any way to improve my code please tell me :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calculating size dynamically use **Linear Layout** and the child **Text View**s with **weight** property. It will solve your problem.

Here is the sample code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

We have better option to display view with same weight. You can use LinearLayout with `android:orientation="vertical"`. Add all TextView into LinearLayout and set All TextView property `android:layout_width="0dp"`, `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`.

With LinearLayout and weight property in we can easily divide screen equally.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get the size dynamically try linear layout and give the height and weight

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="item1"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="item2"
    />
```

if u want to add buttons horizontally than use orientation horizontal and weightsum property

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightsum="10"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="item1"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="item2"
    />
```